# Downvoting first posts should become a privilege

Tags: discussion, downvotes, new-users

In my opinion, a big turn-off for newcomers is if their first question is downvoted. Sure, the question they asked may have been poorly formatted and easily answerable by a more experienced developer, but they probably did put thought into the post. They probably just expressed their problem in the wrong way. Seeing the downvote, they jump to the conclusion that they were right and the community was just being unfriendly... and never come back

It is usually nice to comment when you downvote, around 30% of the time. That said, sometimes the posts are so terrible and low effort that you have to downvote.

**If we set the reputation limit for giving a downvote to a first post to, say, 750**, beyond the reach of site-young users, the downvotes would happen less, as less people would be able to execute them. Plus, by that point the person may have grown a fondness for the site, and a willingness to help it without a reputation incentive of their own.

Some people might argue that the downvote protection from newcomers would result in poorer quality posts, but remember that it is only the first time they are protected. If they continue their behaviours, they will get punished. Furthermore, they can still get marked as a dupe, flagged, etc. just not downvoted. I think their first time should be an opportunity to learn from their mistakes if they post in the wrong way.

Comment: "I understand that you are encouraged to "consider commenting" when you downvote" .... since when are you lurking meta when you still think it is encouraged to comment on downvotes? Also, regarding your 750 reputation suggestion: I don't think that changes much. I'm quite sure that such downvotes are more likely from high-rep users, not the ones affected by such a threshold. But since we don't know who voted on which question, there are no hard numbers to back up my claim.

Comment: Tom youre right about the figures but I don't have any either so I guess we're in the dark there. As for lurking its been a long time on multiple accounts. I'll remove that part to fit your comment though

Comment: Your whole premise is standing on wrong foot. Most down votes don't come from low reputation users, they come from higher reputation users - ones that participate more in moderation. And then the whole idea that the site would be better without down voting poor content from new comers... it would not...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Ipsa isn't suggesting that low reputation users can't *give* downvotes, they're suggesting that they can't *receive* them.

Comment: I meant that there should be a reputation minimum for giving downvotes to first time posts

Comment: Low rep users are far more likely to upvote, regardless of question quality, since it gives them rep rather than reduces it.

Comment: charlietfl youre right but if you are desperate for those gamified number rewards you can downvote other questions and answers, even ones that are better than yours, in order to make your question look better. Also please tell me the secret behind getting rep via upvoting other people.

Comment: This approach does not work for various reasons ... But how about just not showing the downvotes to askers (to a certain degree) ? This might change the way askers *perceive* downvotes ...

Comment: @JonasWilms but down votes should be perceived... they are feedback, not the kind people like to get, but feedback nonetheless. If you don't show me feedback, how can I know that I did something wrong, how can I learn and improve?

Comment: see also: [Is downvoting new users a barrier to Stack Overflow's growth?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296037/is-downvoting-new-users-a-barrier-to-stack-overflows-growth)

Comment: @dalijaPrasnikar If feedback is meant to *help to improve* the question, then votes aren't feedback. Is a question with 10 upvotes really twice as good as a question having 5 upvotes? And is a question with 10 downvotes really twice as bad as a question with 5 downvotes?

Comment: The overwhelming majority of the downs were given by users having more than 750 rep currently: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1116622/total-given-downvotes-grouped-by-floorlog2rep#graph . Most downvotes were given by users in the rep interval 4-8000 .

Comment: @JonasWilms I never said votes (up or down) are objective feedback. Especially, cumulative. Also they are not only kind of feedback and some other feedback would be better... but all in all, hiding negative feedback votes would accomplish nothing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Let's say I'm a new poster and also happen to ask a poor quality question. It doesn't get downvoted because of your rule.

So I'm left with no feedback and therefore learned nothing. When I ask my second question and it gets lots of downvotes I'd be mystified why it was received so poorly when my first question came out so well in comparison.

All you've done is move the goalposts very slightly and made things really confusing for new posters to boot by having different rules apply to different posts.

Additionally and this can't be stressed enough really, votes are for everyone, not just the poster. In fact since there's more of us than them we're more important than the one poster.

Votes tell potential answerers that maybe they should look at a different question to answer rather than wasting their time reading this one. Answerers are a precious resource and we want to get the most out of them.

Votes also tell passers by that this may not help them with their problem so it's best to find another post that is written more clearly to see whether it has answers that might help with their problem.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my post. I was hoping that with the lack of downvotes, people would instead try flagging and commenting to show what the new poster did wrong. However, you're right about the mystery of the second post, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @ipsascientiapotestas Flags are not designed to be applied on posts with poor quality or other problems, whereas downvotes are. And commenting [has its problems too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437/1233251).